# Code Comparison for Same Result Between ksor PHP and sort VB.Net

Tags: php, arrays, vb.net, sorting

I need to sort array on `VB.Net` that equivalent of `ksort` on `PHP`.
I try to compare both of them but the result is different.
Here is my **PHP Code**:

```php
<?php
$parameter['data[1000].isi']= '0';
$parameter['data[111].isi']= '0';
$parameter['data[112].isi']= '0';
$parameter['data[100].isi']= '0';
$parameter['data[3].isi']= '0';
$parameter['data[2].isi']= '0';
$parameter['data[1].isi']= '0';
$parameter['data[0].isi']= '0';

ksort($parameter);

foreach($parameter as $key => $val){
    echo $key." = ".$val."<br />";
}
?>
```

The **output** goes:

```
data[0].itemNo = 0
data[1000].isi = 0
data[100].isi = 0
data[111].isi = 0
data[112].isi = 0
data[1].isi = 0
data[2].isi = 0
data[3].isi = 0
```

And here is my **VB.NET Code**:

```vb
        Dim isi As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        isi.Add("data[1000].isi", 0)
        isi.Add("data[111].isi", 0)
        isi.Add("data[112].isi", 0)
        isi.Add("data[100].isi", 0)
        isi.Add("data[3].isi", 0)
        isi.Add("data[2].isi", 0)
        isi.Add("data[1].isi", 0)
        isi.Add("data[0].isi", 0)

        Dim coba As New ArrayList()
        Dim str, strisi As String
        For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In isi
            coba.Add(kvp.Key & "=" & kvp.Value)
        Next
        coba.Sort()

        For Each apa As String In coba
            str = str & "&" & apa
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = str
```

The **output** goes:

```
&data[0].isi=0
&data[1].isi=0
&data[100].isi=0
&data[1000].isi=0
&data[111].isi=0
&data[1111].isi=0
&data[112].isi=0
&data[2].isi=0
&data[3].isi=0
```

Output of both sorting is different. I need to make `VB.Net` Output same with `PHP` output.
Hot to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using VB 2005 or later then you should not be using an `ArrayList`.  Use a `List(Of String)` instead.  Then you can change this:

```vb
coba.Sort()
```

to this:

```vb
coba.Sort(Function(x, y) String.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.Ordinal))
```

You can still do something similar with an `ArrayList`, if you really must use one for some reason, but it involves defining your own class:

```vb
Public Class OrdinalStringComparer
    Implements IComparer

    Public Function Compare(x As Object, y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare
        Return String.Compare(DirectCast(x, String), DirectCast(y, String), StringComparison.Ordinal)
    End Function

End Class
```

and then passing an instance when calling `Sort`:

```vb
coba.Sort(New OrdinalStringComparer)
```

Note that, if you want to know how an ordinal comparison is performed and what the alternatives are, you should check out the documentation for the `StringComparison` enumeration.